MS Office Switch Account dialog box from VBA
Probably easy - but looking for a way to prompt users to change Office accounts in a shared PC environment.
I just want to open the "switch account" dialogue box that appears when clicking 'user' icon in title bar of word/excel etc (top right of window next to minimise/resize/close). Try as I might can't find a reference to it in the object browser. Its probably simple but its driving me crazy. Need it to pop up automatically when word is opened (for example) as lazy users keep forgetting to change accounts.
Thanks in advance.
like "Application.Dialogs(wdDialogToolsOptions).Show" but that is not the dialogue box I am looking for!
